# Get numbers divisible by a given divisor using logical operators in Python

Tags: python, arrays, r

I want to get a logical answer (TRUE/FALSE) whether the number from a list is divisible by a given divisor.

This is the way I was doing it in R.

```
array = (1:100)
i = 3

sel <- !as.logical(array %% i) 

print(sel)
```

The result looks like that :

```
[1]  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[15] TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[29] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[43] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[57] TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[71] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[85] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[99] TRUE FALSE
```

Is it possible to get a similar outcome in Python?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something similar using `numpy`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1, 101)
>>> i = 3
>>> a % i == 0
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *list comprehension* taking the *mod* of each item in the range :

```
>>> [x % 3 == 0 for x in range(1, 101)]
[False, False, True, False, False, True, False, ...]
```